# How to find symbol in current file in Appcode

Tags: appcode

[image]

How to search symbol in current file? Just like 'control+6' in Xcode.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are most probably looking for, is called a "File Structure" popup. At least, with my mappings it gets opened by pressing `CMD + F12`. Although you won't see a search box, all these popups are filterable. You can get to what you are looking for, by directly typing a few letters of its name.

Hope, my answer can help you.